# Reducer passing state as props in a component undefined

Tags: reactjs, reducers

My Reducer and Actions are working fine and I am logging my data through, but my logs in component where I am consuming my reducers state returns props as [object object], I am sure I am not logging it correctly or reading the json in right format. Here is the code:

**reportReducer.js**

```
import { GET_REPORTS, GET_REPORT_BY_ID } from '../actions/types';
const initialState = {
    reports: [],
    report: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_REPORTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                reports: action.payload
            };
        case GET_REPORT_BY_ID:
            return {
                ...state,
                report: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**reportActions.js**

```
import {GET_REPORTS, GET_REPORT_BY_ID} from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const getReports = () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/report`);
    dispatch({
        type: GET_REPORTS,
        payload: res.data
    });
};

export const getReportById = id => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get(`api/report/${id}`);
    console.log(res.data);
    dispatch({
        type: GET_REPORT_BY_ID,
        payload: res.data
    });
};
```

ReportById.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {getReportById} from '../../actions/reportActions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class ReportById extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        this.props.getReportById(this.props.match.params.id);
    };

    render() {
          console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
          console.log(this.props);   \\this gives [object object]


        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                   <ul>
                    {report && report.title && (
                       <li > {report.title} | {report.assetType} </li>
                                )}
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    reports: state.report.reports,
    report: state.report.report
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getReportById})(ReportById);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing an Object with `console.log` will always print `[object Object]`. This happens because console.log will try to convert it's arguments to string by calling `toString` on them.

If you need to print an object please try something like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props, null, 2));
```

You can skip the second and third arguments to stringify if unformatted JSON is okay for you.

Please note that this won't work if you are passing any circular object in props.

Answer (score 0):

you reducer is GET_ASSET_BY_ID
and you action is GET_REPORT_BY_ID

Comment: that was an error I made while typing here... my code has GET_REPORT_BY_ID in reducer and actons